# grails how to check if value is in list in gsp

Tags: list, grails, gsp

I'm getting a list back from my action that I want to check against another value in the GSP.  I want to be able to see if the value is in the list that gets returned.  I know you can do direct comparison

```
<g:if a="a">
```

but what I am looking for is a string in array comparison

```
<g:if a in [a,b,c,d]>
```

Need something like

```
<g:if test="${myList}.contains(${username})}">
```

Tried:

```
<g:if test="${myList.contains(username)}">
```

and everything is returning false (even when contains should be true)

Test Data:

```
        ${myList.keySet()}
        ${username}

<g:if test="${failedToSync.keySet().contains(username)}">
                <li>${username} yes</li>
            </g:if>
            <g:else>
                <li>${username} no</li>         
            </g:else>
```

outputs:

```
[a] b
b no
[a] a
a no
```

Additional info:

`"${username.stripIndent() == failedToSync.keySet()[0]}"` returns true

```
<g:if test="${(failedToSync.keySet()).contains(username.stripIndent())}"> returns false
```

Comment: `<g:if test="${myList.contains(username)}">` should do what you want, are you certain that the list definitely contains the right things?  For example if `myList` were a list of `User` objects and `username` were a `String` then it would (correctly) always return false.

Comment: @IanRoberts Verified both objects by using getClass() and verified they're both strings

Comment: You've got some input from user and trying to compare that value without reloading the page? I think you need to write some javascript maybe with AJAX.

Comment: might be a bit late for my input I was just doing something similar in my case it was myList.contains(instance.id) this didn't work until I changed it to myList.containst(instance.id as String). The ids was being sent back via json to controller and recollected hence changed type. Cloaks and daggers always test by doing something.getClass()

Answer (score 3):

In Groovy you can use `.contains` on any collection. So, for your case

```
<g:if test="${['a', 'b', 'c'].contains('a')}">
...
</g:if>
```

Comment: sorry, guess I need to be a little more specific....

<g:if test="${myList}.contains(${username})}"> returns true on both valid and invalid cases

Comment: That's because it should be <g:if test="${myList.contains(username)}">

Comment: Then you aren't comparing apples to apples. Is the data in myList the same class as username? E.g. are they both Strings? I promise you, it's doing a compare on the two.

Comment: added more information to the question... I think i'm close but don't know why

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom tag if you like:

`grails-app/taglib/com/demo/StackOverflowTagLib.groovy`

```
package com.demo

class StackOverflowTagLib {
    static namespace = 'my'

    // ...

    def isInList = { attrs, body ->
        def val = attrs.val
        def list = attrs.collection
        if(val in list) {
            out << body()
        }
    }
}
```

`grails-app/views/demo/index.gsp`

```
<html>
<body>
    <my:isInList val="Jeff" collection="${names}">
        Yep, Jeff was in there.
    </my:isInList>
</body>
</html>
```

`grails-app/controllers/com/demo/DemoController.groovy`

```
package com.demo

class DemoController {

    def index() {
        [names: ['Jeff', 'Betsy', 'Zack', 'Jake']]
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have answered your own question: Yes, like

```
<g:if test="${'a' in ['a','b','c','d']}">
    Some Content
</g:if>
```

Comment: Not working for some reason, see last part of question

Comment: The code you pasted should be like `<g:if test="${myList.contains(username)}">`

Comment: that's returning false every time

    [a] b
    b no
    [a] a
    a no

Comment: Can you provide content of `myList` and `username`?

Comment: added more information to the question... I think i'm close but don't know why

Comment: You are printing `${myList.keySet()}` and comparing with `failedToSync.keySet()`. What is the content of `failedToSync.keySet()`.